# Помогите разобраться с кодом скрипта javascript на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется рабочий код скрипта:

```
$(function () {
    var a = $("#news_content,#otsivi_content");
    var c = a.offset(),
        marginTop = parseFloat(a.css('marginTop'))||0,
        d = Math.max($(a[0]).outerHeight(!0), $(a[1]).outerHeight(!0)),
        e = $("#contant_bottom").parents('tr').offset();
    if(c.top+d + 10 >= e.top+marginTop ) return;
    a.css({position:'fixed'});
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var b = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(c.top > b && b < e.top - d) a.css({top : (c.top - b - marginTop)+'px'
        })
        else if (b < e.top - d + marginTop) a.css({top: -marginTop +'px'})
        else a.css({top: (e.top - d  - b) +'px'})

    })
});
```

В нем два блока (`#news_content`, `#otsivi_content`) при прокрутке страницы прилипают к верху экрана и идут до нижнего блока (`#contant_bottom`), затем останавливаются.

Как сделать так, чтобы блоки прилипали не к самому верху, а были смещены, допустим, на 100 пикселей от верха.

Я голову ломаю, не могу понять, т.к. не сам писал этот скрипт.

Comment: попробуйте изменить параметр `marginTop=100;`

Answer (score 1):

в строку
`a.css({top : (c.top - b - marginTop)+'px' })`
добавить желаемое число пикселей:
`a.css({top : (c.top - b - marginTop)+ 100 +'px' })`

Answer (score 0):

@lexxl, я изменил параметры

```
else if (b < e.top - d + marginTop) a.css({top: -marginTop +'px'})
    else a.css({top: (e.top - d  - b) +'px'})
```

на

```
else if (b < e.top - d + marginTop) a.css({top: -marginTop +100 +'px'})
    else a.css({top: (e.top - d  - b) + 100 +'px'})
```

Получилось, но не совсем то что мне нужно. Теперь при прокручивании страницы до нужного мне блока как только он касается верха экрана сразу прыгает на +100 пикселей вниз и закрепляется. А мне нужно что бы касался не верха экрана а +100 пикселей от него.

Comment: прежде всего, то поле, куда вы всё это написали, служит для ответов на вопрос, а не для комментариев или новых вопросов. следует перенести всё это в комментарии к моему ответу. кроме того, я писал про правку строки `if(c.top > b && b < e.top - d) a.css({top : (c.top - b - marginTop)+'px'` , а вы почему-то правили значения в другой. а в целом, в вашем коде сложно что-то понять, потому что вместо осмысленных переменных там муть типа переменных `a`, `b` и `c`. рекомендую всё же самому разобраться (возможно даже переписать по-человечески), как оно там работает, тогда всё станет на свои места.